# ASP.NET MVC and mobile website development

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mobile

Good Morning.

We want to modify our MVC website to use different views in order to service the different mobile resolutions across android and iOS. Is there a framework or recommendation in how can we achieve this?

Comment: use Bootstrap as Microsoft suggests

Comment: Actually Mvc provides those itself...In views if you name a view like `Home.android` it will detect and display an like wise for iOS..If you are targeting responsiveness in your application then you can go with Bootstrap